# exiftool SubSecDateTimeOriginal is not working on aws lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, perl, aws-lambda, exiftool

I am trying to run exiftool on aws lambda and everything runs fine except when I am trying to update image with `SubSecDateTimeOriginal`, it is not working.

I tried below command:

```
cmd = ['/opt/bin/exiftool', '-SubSecDateTimeOriginal="2021:11:30 03:47:50.084+00:00"', '-overwrite_original', '/mnt/processing/000001.jpg']
output = subprocess.run( cmd, capture_output=True )
print(output)
```

and **it did update the `DateTimeOriginal` but not `SubSecDateTimeOriginal`**

```
cmd = ['/opt/bin/exiftool', '-ee', '-G3', '-X', '-SubSecDateTimeOriginal', '-DateTimeOriginal', '/mnt/processing/000001.jpg']
output = subprocess.run( cmd, capture_output=True )
print(output)
```

and on output I am only getting `DateTimeOriginal` and `SubSecDateTimeOriginal` is missing

```
<ExifIFD:DateTimeOriginal>2021:11:30 03:47:50</ExifIFD:DateTimeOriginal>\n</rdf:Description>
```

For aws lambda environment I am using:

perl: `https://shogo82148-lambda-perl-runtime-eu-west-2.s3.amazonaws.com/perl-5-34-runtime.zip`

exiftool: `version: 12.30`

**It is working perfectly on local system but not on lambda.**

Can anyone please tell me, what could cause this and how can i fix it.

**EDIT**

I am getting this error:

```
1 files updated
Warning: Error converting value for ExifIFD:SubSecTimeOriginal (ValueConvInv)
```

**There is one very weird thing, if i use with `os.system("...")` then it works but when i try i with `subprocess.run("...")` then it does not work.**

can anyone tell what could be the reason?

Comment: There is one very weird thing, if i use with os.system("...") then it works but when i try i with subprocess.run("...") then it does not work.

Comment: Catch exiftool exit error codes, monitor STDERR, inspect environment, try to reproduce errors manually in shell.

Comment: I'm confused about the value you want to store there. `SubSecTime...` is the fractional part of the seconds value, I would expect that only "084" has to be written there, not the whole "2021:11:30 03:47:50.084+00:00"

Comment: I figured out the answer, it worked after removing the quote from the values, `'-SubSecDateTimeOriginal="2021:11:30 03:47:50.084+00:00"'` -> `'-SubSecDateTimeOriginal=2021:11:30 03:47:50.084+00:00'`

But can anyone explain why? because for some systems it is working with quotes too.

If anyone can please explain this I'll award bounty to them :)

Comment: The quotations aren't needed because subprocess' Popen constructor, that is called from `run()`, will automatically handle escaping and quoting when the args passed are a sequence (e.g. list, tuple). If you passed the command as a string then you would need to handle it yourself in the string.